# Can't remove framework from Xcode link step

Tags: ios, xcode

I am migrating a project from xcode 7.3 to 8.1 and for now just converting to swift 2.3 (from 2.2).  Its been a struggle, particularly with objective c frameworks that had been added via cocoapods.

I currently am having an issue were I can't seem to get rid of a reference to one framework in the link step.

When I try to build the project it fails in the link step with:

```
  ld: framework not found DateTools
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and I can see this on the command that is failing:

```
... -framework CoreText -framework DateTools -framework GLKit ...
```

I have removed the framework and currently I am just including the files I need in the project.

Here is what I have done so far :

1. cleaned the project
2. exited xcode
3. removed the framework from the Podfile, removed the Pods directory and then reinstalled the remaining pods
4. searched entire project (via a script) for DateTools and removed anything I found
5. deleted derived data
6. restarted computer

But the problem remains.

One interesting thing I did find, is that when I searched the Derived data folder (prior to deleting it),  I **do** see an entry `-framework DateTools` in a file called `dgph`

```
found pattern in OurLatitude-eliemxgbqrgibwbimtxzdyhuagll/Build/Intermediates/OurLatitude.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OurLatitude.build/dgph
line: 68 -framework DateTools
```

Which I came to find is some sort of dependency graph used by xcode.  The problem is that even after I delete the Derived data, once I restart xcode this file seems to be re-created and still contains the same entry.

Is there some other place I should be looking for this framework entry?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this!  Turns out I missed entry in my one of my projects files.  I was fooled because I still expected some DateTools strings to show up (since I tried to include the files manually).  Once I fully removed everything to do with DateTools, I was surprised to still see a DateTools string show up.

The entry was `"-framework" "\"DateTools\"",`  under `OTHER_LDFLAGS` in

```
~/development/ourlatitude/OurLatitude.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

(So basically exactly what the linker was complaining about).

After removing that entry, I was able to re-install DateTools via cocoapods.

I think there are really two common causes of `ld: framework not found XXXX`

1. Is caused by what I had above
2. Is caused by having an old/bad import in one of your test files.

for example my next issue after clearing the above was a similar message but this time it was caused by this in one of my test files:

```
import ObjectMapper
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import OurLatitude
```

changing that to this:

```
//import ObjectMapper
//import Alamofire
//import AlamofireObjectMapper
@testable import OurLatitude
```

resolved my last issue and I was able to get a clean build with swift 2.3 in xcode 8.1

Hopefully this will help someone else, or at least I will find it next time I hit a `ld: framework not found XXXX`

Comment: interesting note: i had the same issue when I was upgrading cocoapod versions. my problem was in my xcodeproj, as well, in my build settings. once i removed my stale framework from "Other linker flags", the build worked